# Elasticsearch javascript using NodeJS not installing

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Not sure if I missed something, I have installed the latest under NPM

```
npm install elasticsearch
```

I would have expected an elasticsearch folder in my `node_modules`, but it shows up as elasticsearch-browser.  I believe they are the same code so I was not too alarmed.

In my node code:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch-browser');
```

I get an error:

> Dev/node_modules/elasticsearch-browser/elasticsearch.js:20281 var
>   parseInt = nativeParseInt(whitespace + '08') == 8 ? nativeParseInt :
>   funct
>                  ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function

Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry - not sure how or why, but i installed again and got the actual elasticsearch node library and all is well with the world.